# IOException : stream closed, BitmapFactory decodeStream

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, inputstream

I'm getting from an API a Stream which is a Picture. I get the stream in the `doInBackground of the Asynctask` I get no crashes or `NullPointerException` against that `InputStream`. But when I try to build a bitmap using it it always returns me `stream is closed` and I don't close it at all.

```
private class Worker extends Asynctask<.....> {

    private StreamSource streamSource;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    public void doInBackground (.....) {
        try {
            streamSource = gallery.read ();

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (streamSource.getStream ()); // HERE ! :@

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute (.....) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap (bmp);
    }
}
```

this is the exception I get :

```
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359): java.io.IOException: stream closed
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.checkNotClosed(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:68)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$ChunkedInputStream.read(HttpTransport.java:430)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:634)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at com.package.activities.MediasActivity$Worker.doInBackground(MediasActivity.java:158)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-12 22:33:00.973: W/System.err(20359):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-12 22:33:00.973: D/skia(20359): ---- read threw an exception
08-12 22:33:00.973: D/skia(20359): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

The exception is thrown in : `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`

I can assure that I'm not closing the stream, If i would like to do it I would have done : `streamSource.close ();` But I didn't.

Do you guys, have any idea about what could be the reason of this ? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I would have to assume that it's not wrong and that the stream is in fact closed. At what point is the stream being opened?

Comment: @Hypino : Thank you :) The stream is being opened in `read ()`

Answer (score 0):

BitmapFactory.decodeStream most likely closes the stream after it is done. If you are sharing streamSources between your AsyncTask workers, it's possible one is closing a stream and another one is trying to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decoding your stream using  runOnUiThread ? For example write

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            streamSource = gallery.read ();

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (streamSource.getStream ()); // HERE ! :@

        }
    });
```

Comment: What would be the difference between using `Runnable` and `Asynctask` ?

Comment: and FYI All the heavy stuff should be done on the Background :)